# The icon on on contacts display list is not changing with Drupal 7 , is my path ok?

Tags: drupal

Changing icon path for contact type is not working, I tried different kinds of paths but no go...

I tried this:

```
default/files/partners.png
```

and this:

```
../../../default/files/partners.png
```

This is my goal:

https://imagebin.ca/v/4Edzm7RF4NyH

Attaching image to explain:

[image]

Comment: Can you update the question with the full path to your CiviCRM root and the full path to the image?

Comment: Sure:  C:/Core/XAMPP_2018/htdocs/crm4   or   C:/Core/XAMPP_2018/htdocs/crm4/sites/all/modules/civicrm  or  C:/Core/XAMPP_2018/htdocs/crm4/sites/default/files/partners.png

Comment: Hmm - not sure if it will work, but try using backslashes instead of forward slashes in the Image URL because you're on Windows?  If this DOES work, we should probably report it as a bug, Civi should detect/convert these IMO.

Comment: Before I report it as a bug, what is the EXACT way to enter URL in windows 10, I'm on Xampp also. I inputed an icon online and it worked, so it's simply a path instruction problem ;)

Comment: I'm afraid I've never installed CiviCRM on Windows so I can't tell you, sorry!

Comment: Thanks, no biggie, I've uploaded the icons online, I give up on this for now, hopefully someday someone can help ; Thanks Jon